# changing font-weight for TVML elements

Tags: css, xml, tvos, tvml

I'm currently working on a TVML app for the **Apple TV**, and I've been trying to do a few styling adjustments to a few elements.

I've been able to follow [the TVML documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ITMLStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH11-SW1) and I've successfully changed the text colour from white to black by doing this:

```
<description style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0)"> 
  Selvage banjo authentic messenger bag, pork belly occupy heirloom...etc
</description>
```

Now, according to the documentation, I'd like to style it further by changing other styles such as `font-weight` to `light`, and `font-size`.

Here are a few of my attempts in doing so:

## 1

```
<description style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0); font-weight: light"> 
  text goes here
</description>
```

## 2

```
<description style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0) font-weight: light">
  text goes here
</description>
```

## 3

```
<description style="font-weight: light">
  text goes here
</description>
```

## 4

```
<description font-weight="light">
  text goes here
</description>
```

I can't figure out how to get it working, unfortunately. I'm using the `descriptiveAlertTemplate`.

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set tv-text-style: none - for example:

```
<description style="tv-text-style: none; font-size:36; font-weight:regular;">
```